# Передать содержимое блока в переменную php

Tags: php

Есть блок с содержимым `id="data"`, и скрипт записи в файл. Подскажите пожалуйста, как присвоить переменной `$str` содержимое блока `id="data"`, чтобы записать в файл. Сейчас записывается 'Привет мир'

```
<div id="data"></div>

<?php
$fd = fopen("file.txt", 'w') or die("не удалось создать файл");
$str = "Привет мир";
fputs($fd, $str);
fclose($fd);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конце страницы , где находится id=data вставь скрипт

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'index.php',
            data: $("#data").val(),
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log('It OK')
}
       
     });
});
</script>`
```

И в php файле получи ее из POST

Comment: $str = $_POST['  '].  Так? А что должно быть здесь ['  '] ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: в php файле var_dump($_POST). И там все видно .